# Counting the number of names in a category in a .csv with bash

Tags: bash, csv, sh

I would like to count the number of students in a .csv file depending on the category

Category 1 is the name, Category 2 is the country, Category 3 is the city

The .csv file is displayed as such :

```
michael_s;jpa;NYC
john_d;chn;TXS
jim_h;usa;POP
```

I have tried in my .sh script but it didn't work

```
sort -k3 -t; students.csv
```

**edit:**

I am trying to make a bash script that counts students by city and something that can also count one city just by executing the script such as

```
cat students.csv | ./script.sh NYC
```

The terminal will only display the students from NYC

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: it says "sort: multi-character tab 'students.csv'" but doesn't actually do anything

Comment: an error message is not the expected result, it's obvious

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, something like this?

```
cut -d";" -f3 mike.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

(Sorry, incorrect solution first time - updated now)

To count only one city:

cut -d";" -f3 mike.txt | grep "NYC" | wc -l

Depending on the size of the file, how often you'll be doing this etc. it may be sensible to look at other solutions, eg. awk. But this solution will work just fine.

Comment: I sorted and counted on field 3. If you want to count on a different field then change the -f3 in the cut to the field you want to count on.

Comment: I..e to count by country, use cut -d";" -f2, to count by name use cut -d";" -f1

Comment: Is there a way to only count one city? such as ./script.sh NYC and it will display only the number of students of NYC

Comment: I've upated the solution. If you want to pass the value into the script as a parm, then use $1 instead of "NYC" (or whichever parameter number it is - personally I usually assign the parameters to specific vars in the script at the start for clarity).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error message "sort: multi-character tab 'students.csv'" is you haven't given the `-t` option the separator character. If you add a semicolon after `-t`, the sort will work as expected:

```
sort -k3 -t';' students.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always awk:

```
$ awk -F\; 'a[$1]++==0{c++}END{print c}' file
3
```

Once you describe your requirements more throughly, (*count the names* but `sort -k3`. Update the OP, please) we can help you better.

Edited to match your update:

```
$ awk -F\; -v col=3 -v val=NYC '
(length(val) && $col==val) || length(val)==0 && a[$col]++==0 {
    c++
}
END { print c }
' file
1
```

If you set `-v val=` with the value you are looking for and `-v col=` with the column number, it counts the occurrences of `val` in `col`. You you set `col` but not `val` ot counts different values in `col`.

Comment: It only display 1, not the number of students in a particular city

Comment: This is better than my cut/sort/uniq solution. You should use this if you can. Unless possibly the files you're checking are all rather small, in which case it probably makes little difference and the "basic" solution is then maybe more readable for future reference by people that don't have a lot of *nix knowledge.

Comment: @AlanS. So it seems. Apparently it needs more tweaking than I first thought.

Comment: @AlanS. How about now (btw, you could post more definitive data sample with expected output)?

Comment: @urbanspaceman I can't do that :( I must do something so that when the user executes the script, it displays the number of students by country but also makes it display only the numbers of which country asked when executing the script with the name of the country such as (cat students.csv | ./script.sh NYC) or (cat students.csv | ./script.sh POP)

Comment: @James Brown it works but it only counts NYC, I want it to count other cities as well

Comment: @AlanS. You can use either solution with or without a variable passed in (i.e. to get only one or all). You'll need to use the alternative method I gave you for "basic" commands, and the awk will need amending to deal with all and not just one. 

Then you'd put an if statement in your script to call the correct command depending on whether a parameter had been passed or not (or perhaps you pass "*" för all or something like that)